# Does Turing Completeness imply the existence of a Universal Program?

Tags: computability, turing-machines, turing-completeness, church-turing-thesis

Please correct me if at any time my definitions are wrong.
Suppose we have a programming language $L$ over some set $D$ with semantic (partial) n-ary functions $\varphi^n:D \to (D^n \to D)$. Assume $L \subseteq D$ (so programs are data as well).

- We say that $L$ is turing complete if a function $f:D^n\to D$ is Turing Computable if and only if there exists a program $p \in L$ such that $f = \varphi^n(p)$.
- We know there exists a universal Turing Machine: A Turing Computable function $U:D^2 \to D$ such that for every (encoding of) a Turing Computable function $T$, every $d \in D$: $U(T,d) = T(d)$.
- Does this imply, via Turing Completeness, that there must be a universal program in $L$? Why or why not?

Comment: What are your thoughts?  What have you tried so far?  Have you tried looking for a counterexample?  for a proof?   (It's also hard to tell what you mean by the notation $\varphi$, $\varphi^n$, and $\varphi_T$: are they supposed to be related in some way?  You should specify how.)

Comment: @D.W. I would say yes, since $U$ is Turing Computable then it should be $L$-computable as well. I fixed the notation, it should be more clear now. The part about encodings and such confuses me, so I do not know really where to start looking for a proof/counter example.